# Best known attack

Tags: cryptanalysis

I always have listened the term **best known attack** but I have doubts respect to this term, becase there are several kinds of attacks for example structural attacks, inversion attacks. It is possible to get the best known attack of all kinds of attacks? Where Can I read about formalization of the term best know attack?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you could also read "known best attack" instead of "best known attack".

In that case the attack would simply be the attack that reduces the security the most. This is often calculated in powers of two, represented by bits.

For instance an attack could reduce security from 112 bits to 80 bits. If a second attack only reduces security from 112 bits to, say, 90 bits then the first attack mentioned is the known best attack / best, known, attack.

There *could be* other, unknown attacks that reduce security further, hence **known** best attack.

Comment: Be careful though, not only the security reduction should be taken into account. Some attacks may e.g. have implicit high memory requirements.

Comment: @Aleph Good point. However I'm not sure if there is any way of weighing memory requirements (or any other requirements) against security reduction. That's probably pretty subjective, unless the boundaries are a given.

Comment: Me neither, but it seemed important to warn future readers :).

Comment: @MaartenBodewes thanks, but whats about my quesiton: It is possible to get the best known attack of all kinds of attacks?

Comment: According to my answer that would be the one that compromises the security the most. What kind of information are you missing? What kind of conditions do you set? Please be as specific as possible.